# Error when compiling lirc-redrat3-0.8.7

Tags: linux, lirc

When configuring lirc-redrat3-0.8.7, I've got this issues :

http://www.redrat.co.uk/downloads/lirc-redrat3-0.8.7.tar.gz

```
     ./configure 
    ......
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
.....
    checking for python... /usr/bin/python
    checking for python version... 2.7
    checking for python platform... linux2
    checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
.....
    checking for _doprnt... no
    checking for gethostname... yes
    checking for gettimeofday... yes
    checking for mkfifo... yes
    checking for select... yes
    checking for socket... yes
    checking for strdup... yes
    checking for strerror... yes
    checking for strtoul... yes
    checking for snprintf... yes
    checking for strsep... yes
    checking for vsyslog... yes
    checking for forkpty... no
    checking for forkpty in -lutil... yes
    checking vga.h usability... no
    checking vga.h presence... no
    checking for vga.h... no
    checking for X... libraries , headers 
    checking for gethostbyname... yes
    checking for connect... yes
    checking for remove... yes
    checking for shmat... yes
    checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
    checking for getopt_long... yes
    checking for mktemp... yes
    checking for Linux kernel sources... /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic-pae/build/
    checking for which drivers can be installed on this system... 
    checking for caraca_init in -lcaraca_client... no
    checking ftdi.h usability... no
    checking ftdi.h presence... no
    checking for ftdi.h... no
    checking iguanaIR.h usability... no
    checking iguanaIR.h presence... no
    checking for iguanaIR.h... no
    checking for ir_strerror in -lirman... yes
    checking for ir_strerror in -lirman_sw... yes
    checking portaudio.h usability... no
    checking portaudio.h presence... no
    checking for portaudio.h... no
    checking alsa/asoundlib.h usability... no
    checking alsa/asoundlib.h presence... no
    checking for alsa/asoundlib.h... no
    checking scsi/sg.h usability... yes
    checking scsi/sg.h presence... yes
    checking for scsi/sg.h... yes
    checking linux/input.h usability... yes
    checking linux/input.h presence... yes
    checking for linux/input.h... yes
    checking linux/types.h usability... yes
    checking linux/types.h presence... yes
    checking for linux/types.h... yes
    checking for linux/hiddev.h... yes
    checking for HIDDEV_FLAG_UREF support... yes
    checking sys/soundcard.h usability... yes
    checking sys/soundcard.h presence... yes
    checking for sys/soundcard.h... yes
    checking linux/i2c-dev.h usability... yes
    checking linux/i2c-dev.h presence... yes
    checking for linux/i2c-dev.h... yes
    configure: error: no driver specified, try ./configure --help
```

Does any one know this error ?

Comment: Resolved after installing libasound2-dev. But new error when compiling:
fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting *#include linux/smp_lock.h* in lirc_redrat3.c and lirc_dev.c, It was correctly compiling :-)

*linux/smp_lock.h* is the header file for the "Big Kernel Lock", which no longer exists as of 2.6.39.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the redrat site informs us that the redrat driver is built into the kernel from 3.3. If you are using an older kernel the best way might be to update the kernel and use a standard lirc installation (using the "default" driver which is layered on top of the kernel driver).

The lirc version distributed by redrat is really, really old (2010) and a lot of things has happened since, both with the kernel and with lirc. I would avoid trying to make it work, even if it might be possible.